# How to show default lock screen instead of my launcher app in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

My app is an android launcher so when I set it as default on my device and if the phone is sleeping I don't see my default device's lock screen after switching it on again, instead I am able to use my app.

Note: I can operate my app even when I haven't unlocked my phone but after I launch an app, the default lock screen is prompted.

How can I show the default lock screen when the phone goes to sleep or an alternative where I can at least know the state of the device so that I can put together a screen or something.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'My app is an android launcher'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid use of your app when phone is locked then open Androidmanifest.xml in android -> app -> src -> main and remove or set to false.

```
android:showWhenLocked="true"
```